# Swipe to next fragment

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, touch-event

My app slides out a finished game that is held in a fragment with an animation. Then slides in a new game held in a new fragment.

Questions:

1) Can I have this animation step through the animation based on a finger drag. so that the            animation follows the finger?

2) Currently if I use the animation then rotate to landscape the layout_land uses the animation. The same happens going back to portrait. Can I stop this?

```
"slide_in_right.xml"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:zAdjustment="top" />
</set>

"slide_out_left.xml"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="-100%p"
    android:zAdjustment="top" />
</set>



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    public static final String TAG = "FragTag";
    float x1,x2;
    float y1, y2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView background = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.background);
        background.setImageResource(R.drawable.stars);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        UIrFragment test = new UIrFragment();
        test.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, test, TAG).commit();
    }
}


public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touch_event)
{
    switch (touch_event.getAction())
    {
        // when user first touches the screen we get x and y coordinate
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        {
            x1 = touch_event.getX();
            y1 = touch_event.getY();
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            x2 = touch_event.getX();
            y2 = touch_event.getY();

            if (x1 > x2) {

                UIrFragment transition = new UIrFragment();
                transition.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right,R.anim.slide_out_left);
                ft.replace(android.R.id.content, transition);
                ft.commit();

                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1)try to use custom viewPager

Comment: Have you found any solution on this that you can share?

Comment: @raveN sorry no I didn't push through to get the answer moved on to my next pry